# Re-routes using a method that should have nothing to do with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In a view I call upon a controller method. This however seems to call a different method than I want to do.

The view includes:

```
<%= link_to("Upgrade account", upgrade_path)
```

With routes:

```
  get 'signup/organization' => 'organizations#new',         as: 'register'
  get 'signup/register'     => 'organizations#new_premium', as: 'register_premium'
  post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#checkout',    as: 'signup_checkout'
  post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#upgrade',     as: 'upgrade'
  get 'signup/confirmation' => 'organizations#confirmation'
```

'Upgrade' does not occur anywhere else in my routes file.

The path in the view should thus call upon the following controller method:

```
  def upgrade
    @organization = current_organization
    @actioncode = Actioncode.new
    @amount = DEFAULT_PRICE
    @currency = "EUR"
    @description = @organization.id
    @transaction_description = "MyDescription"
    @transaction_type = "S"
    @hash = hash(@description, @amount, @currency, @transaction_type)
    render 'checkout'
  end
```

This should render a view (checkout.html.erb) which has two forms. However, instead it re-routes to the root with the message `You're already logged in`. As it turns out this message originates from the following controller method:

```
  def new_premium
    if (logged_in_user?)
      flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
    @organization = Organization.new
    @member = @organization.members.build
  end
```

I don't see how that method can come into play and why my code isn't working. Does anyone have an idea?

The controller also contains a `def checkout` but I don't see how that might be of effect. The line `render 'checkout'` I would expect to render checkout.html.erb and have no relationship with either `def checkout` or `def new_premium`... right...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your routes:

```
post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#checkout',    as: 'signup_checkout'
post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#upgrade',     as: 'upgrade'
```

The same url with the same verb is used twice.

The rule in routing is "first match first served", so I guess they are all handled by `checkout`.

Fix is simple, change the url for one of them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought that the name of the route (as: ...) would be leading but apparantly not.

Comment: yeah the `as` is just syntaxic sugar for the url helper names, nothing to do with the urls